# Best way of adding nested sub documents in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a user and a message model. The relation is the following: a user can have many messages.

**Goal:** I'm looking for the best or most elegant way of adding a new message and link it to the corresponding user.

User model:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  register_date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  osrs_messages: [OsrsMessage]
});
```

Message model:

```
const OsrsMessageSchema = new Schema({
  message: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  send_date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});
```

My router that adds a new message and adds the message to the user in question:

```
router.post("/osrs", verifyAccessToken, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { username, message } = req.body;
    // create a new message and save
    let newMessage = new OsrsMessage({ username, message });
    newMessage = await newMessage.save();
    // get the associated user and add new message to messages array
    let user = await User.findById(req.user.id);
    user.osrs_messages.push({ username, message });
    user = await user.save();
    return res.status(200).json({ message: "message received" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error message:", error);
    return res
      .status(500)
      .json({ message: "Oops... looks like something went wrong" });
  }
});
```

Are there any ways I can improve this? Should I use `findOneAndUpdate` or `insert` instead? Can I add a message automatically to my message collection if I link it to a user or do I always have to manually add it to the collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add messages to the collection manually. But you can improve your implementation by using `Populate`

> Population is the process of automatically replacing the specified paths in the document with document(s) from other collection(s)

You can have a good overview of `Populate` [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

The main advantage of using populate is, in the collection, it keeps the reference `_id` of the document and if you need to update any nested document, `OsrsMessage` in your case, you do not need to update/re-insert it in the `User`.

The documentation of [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) has a good overview of how you can use it. I hope this one will help you to improve your current implementation.

You can write in this way,

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
username: {
type: String,
required: true,
unique: true
},
email: {
type: String,
required: true,
unique: true,
},
password: {
type: String,
required: true,
},
register_date: {
type: Date,
default: Date.now
},
osrs_messages: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'OsrsMessage' }]
});
```

In your code add the message in the following way

```
router.post("/osrs", verifyAccessToken, async (req, res) => {
try {
const { username, message } = req.body;
// create a new message and save
let newMessage = new OsrsMessage({ username, message });
newMessage = await newMessage.save();
// get the associated user and add new message to messages array
let user = await User.findById(req.user.id);
user.osrs_messages.push(newMessage._id);
user = await user.save();
return res.status(200).json({ message: "message received" });
} catch (error) {
console.log("error message:", error);
return res
  .status(500)
  .json({ message: "Oops... looks like something went wrong" });
}
});
```

After that, whenever you need to get the user with message you can do the query as like this

```
const user = await User.
    findById(req.user.id).
    populate({ path: 'osrs_messages'}).
    exec();
```

Here you will get the user with all `osrs_messages` as a list

Comment: As of how far I understand populate, I would use populate after creating the new message to set the message fields in the user collection right? Are u able to provide an updated answer on how something like this would look? I'm seeing multiple implementations of populate so I'm not quite sure

Comment: So populate is only used for when you are querying a result? I would still need to add the message to the message collection and then to the user?

Comment: @Dax Yes. But In your implementation, the message was stored 2 times, one as a message and again inside the message collection of the user. Using the populate you are just keeping the `_id` of the created message in the `osrs_messages` collection.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of 2 querys, `findById` and `.save()` you can go with 1 query `updateOne`.

```
router.post("/osrs", verifyAccessToken, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { username, message } = req.body;

    // create a new message and save
    let newMessage = new OsrsMessage({ username, message });

    newMessage = await newMessage.save();

    await User.updateOne({_id: req.user.id}, {
       $push: {
          osrs_messages: newMassage._id
       }
    });

    return res.status(200).json({ message: "message received" });

  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error message:", error);
    return res
      .status(500)
      .json({ message: "Oops... looks like something went wrong" });
  }
});
```